# jQuery scrollTop(0) only takes effect after you scroll

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I have this modal dialog box defined:

```
$("#calendar_dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: true,
            width: 520,
            height: "auto",
            create: function(){ $(this).css("maxHeight",300); },
            buttons: {
                "Close": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

I'm using this jQuery ajax call to load the dialog's content every time it's opened:

```
    var calendar_dialog = $("#calendar_dialog");

$.ajax({
                url:"/cfc/test.cfc",
                data:{
                    method: "getCalendarEventDetails"
                },
                beforeSend: function(){
                    calendar_dialog.html('<div style="text-align:center; width:100%;"><img src="/images/pagetemplate/ajax-loader-lg.gif" /></div>');
                    calendar_dialog.dialog("open");
                },
                success: function(returned_results){
                    calendar_dialog.html(returned_results)
                },
                complete: function(){
                    calendar_dialog.scrollTop(0);
                }
            });
```

I want the vertical scrollbar to be scrolled all the way to the top every time this dialog box opens.

However, here's what's happening: The first time the dialog box is opened, the content is scrolled to the top. If I scroll down within the dialog box, close the dialog box, and reopen it (which relaunches that ajax function), the vertical scrollbar is in the same position as when I closed it. However, at that point, if I scroll within the dialog box, up or down, it pops up to the top first and starts scrolling from there.  So, it's getting the command, but not actually moving the scrollbar to the top until you start scrolling.

How can I fix this to start at the top immediately whenever the dialog box is opened?

Answer (score 0):

Can't say why it's doing what it's doing, but I found a work-around.  I moved the scrollTop(0) command to the beforeSend function, and added a trigger("scroll") to the "complete" function:

```
$.ajax({
            url:<cfoutput>"/cfc/test.cfc"</cfoutput>,
            data:{
                method: "getCalendarEventDetails"
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
                calendar_dialog.scrollTop(0);
                calendar_dialog.html('<div style="text-align:center; width:100%;"><img src="/images/pagetemplate/ajax-loader-lg.gif" /></div>');
                calendar_dialog.dialog("open");
            },
            success: function(returned_results){
                calendar_dialog.html(returned_results)
            },
            complete: function(){
                calendar_dialog.trigger("scroll");
            }
        });
```